# How to declare function type for function with variable number of parameters in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am writing a function that accepts another function and it's arguments, for calling it later.  How do I specify the type of function so that it can have any number of arguments?

Looking for something like this.

```
// this does not compile
fun doLater(func: (vararg) -> Double, args: List<Any>) {
    ...
} 

fun footprintOne(i: int, s: String): Double {...}
fun footprintTwo(cheeses: List<Cheese>): Double {...}

// these should be able to run fine
doLater(::footprintOne, listOf(3, "I love StackOverflow"))
doLater(::footprintTwo, listOf(listOf(blueCheese, bree, havarti)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it isn't possible. [vararg parameter in a Kotlin lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045884/vararg-parameter-in-a-kotlin-lambda)

My best workaround I can suggest is to re-wrap the function into one that takes Array or List for the varargs and take that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `vararg` keyword:

```kotlin
fun doLater(func: (Array<out Any>) -> Double, vararg args: Any) {
    func(args)
}
```

then you call it like this:

```kotlin
doLater(
    { args ->
        // Function logic
    },
    1, 2, 3
)
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs

Comment: Oh dear, it seems I didn't write my question clear enough.  I'll try to update it