# passing array to functional interface but get (Array<out TypeVariable(T)>) -> Array<out TypeVariable(T)>? type mismatch

Tags: kotlin, generics

```
fun main() {
  val changeFirstElement = VarargsFunction<String> { ss: Array<String> ->
    ss[0] = ss[0]!! + " world"
    ss
  }
}

fun interface VarargsFunction<T> {
  fun apply(vararg t: T): Array<out T>?
}
```

I get this following exception: `Type mismatch: inferred type is (Array<String>) -> Array<out String>? but (Array<out TypeVariable(T)>) -> Array<out TypeVariable(T)>? was expected`

Any suggestion why is this exception and how to resolve it? Thanks

Playground link https://pl.kotl.in/kBwQZlCZj

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this? Vararg arrays cannot be modified. This is likely an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Please explain why you are doing this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vararg parameter in a Kotlin lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045884/vararg-parameter-in-a-kotlin-lambda)

Comment: Use `ss: Array<out String>` to fix that type error, and then you'll get a new error on the next line of code because you can't modify the array.